# How to configure Okular to use SVOX pico for its "read text" functionality?

Tags: kde, okular, text-to-speech

Okular has a nice read text functionality that by default uses espeak as a backend. As espeak has a rather robotic voice, I would prefer to use SVOX pico.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that "read-text" functions properly. If not:

```
sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher qtspeech5-speechd-plugin speech-dispatcher-pico
```

Then, configure speech dispatcher by editing the file speechd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
```

comment out the line

```
DefaultModule espeak-ng
```

like this

```
#DefaultModule espeak-ng
```

and add a line like the following

```
DefaultModule pico
```

The above works nice for English. It would be nice to also have a solution for multilingual environments.